# css div arrangement using float and width

Tags: html, css, css-float

What I'm trying to achieve is, 1st div will go all the way to the right end of the screen which is OK, but when I'm trying the make 3 divs share the same row side by side to one another, so I try setting 3 of them with float and make their width 33%. What happens is only 2 of the divs will share the same row, and the 3rd div goes below those 2 divs. They only align when I set width and float to each div, I tried applying the float and width with 3 at once but it wont work, I messed up somewhere and I'm kinda confused on the behaviour of the divs.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
        practice webpage
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="banner">
            contents
            </div>
            <div class="menu1">i am menu 1</div>
            <div class="menu2">i am menu 2</div>
            <div class="menu3">i am menu 3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.banner{
background-color: aqua;
}

.menu1, menu2, menu3 {
float: left;
width: 33%;
}

.menu1{
background-color: crimson;
}

.menu2{
background-color: blueviolet;
}

.menu3{
background-color: darkorange;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo. It should be `.menu1, .menu2, .menu3`

Comment: you're missing the '.' before your classes in '.menu1, menu2, menu3 {' should be '.menu1, .menu2, .menu3 {'

Answer (score 1):

You have to append dots to classes when writing css.

Here update your code:

```
.menu1,
.menu2,
.menu3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Check updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/0qg1hhcj/

I guess this is what you want:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.banner {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.menu1,
.menu2,
.menu3 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
.menu1 {
  background-color: crimson;
}
.menu2 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.menu3 {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="banner">
    contents
  </div>
  <div class="menu1">i am menu 1</div>
  <div class="menu2">i am menu 2</div>
  <div class="menu3">i am menu 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because in css you have written `.menu1, menu2, and menu3` instead of `.menu1, .menu2, .menu3`. Please see this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ashishpce2007/u5dz6up6/).